# Identifying if a graphics card is onboard or pcie

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code to identify all current active graphic cards:

```
    private void Read()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher graphicCards = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_VideoController");

        var allVideoControllers = graphicCards.Get();

        TotalGraphicCards = allVideoControllers.Count;

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in allVideoControllers)
        {
            //Only card which are currently actively processing
            if (obj["CurrentBitsPerPixel"] != null)
            {
                GraphicCards.Add(new GPU
                {
                    AdapterDACType = (string)obj["AdapterDACType"],
                    AdapterRAM = (uint)obj["AdapterRAM"],
                    CapabilityDescriptions = (string[])obj["CapabilityDescriptions"],
                    DeviceID = (string)obj["DeviceID"],
                    DriverVersion = (string)obj["DriverVersion"],
                    InstalledDisplayDrivers = (string)obj["InstalledDisplayDrivers"],
                    MaxRefreshRate = (uint)obj["MaxRefreshRate"],
                    Monochrome = (bool)obj["Monochrome"],
                    Name = (string)obj["Name"],
                    SystemName = (string)obj["SystemName"],
                    VideoArchitecture = (ushort)obj["VideoArchitecture"],
                    VideoMemoryType = (ushort)obj["VideoMemoryType"],
                    VideoProcessor = (string)obj["VideoProcessor"]
                });
            }

            TotalMemory += (uint)obj["AdapterRAM"];
        }

        MaxPrimaryResolution = GetMaximumPrimaryResolution();
    }
```

what I need to identify is if the current card in the loop is onboard or PCIe, is there any way to identify?

Comment: this help at all?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814492/determine-what-if-any-pci-devices-are-plugged-into-motherboard-pcie-slots maybe the two can be combined in some way?

Comment: Why exactly would that be relevant? It's useless to gauge performance capabilities that way (there are plenty of low-end or just old&slow-ish discrete GPUs/cards).

Comment: Because I'm building a tool to visualise where the components are located. The posters use case shouldn't really come into question here.

Comment: There are plenty of "XY problem" questions asked here on SO, so asking about the use case is often a good idea (keep in mind that i and others can just see and read your question, but can't see and read your mind about what problem you actually try to solve / what goal you are trying to achieve)

Comment: Agreed there are lot's of posts that are like that, this isn't one of them. The question is clear and requires no 'mind reading' to ascertain that the poster needs to find a way to identify onboard or PCIe cards.